# Decreasing an amount of number that person receives by calculating a percentage for each

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

I need to calculate a percentage for each person in my list (100 participants) with certain conditions:

1. We know how many percents to put for first 3 people

> 1st person - 20%
>
> 2nd person - 15%
>
> 3rd person - 5%

2. We also have a percentage that receives the last 100th participant

> 100th place - 0.25%

Please, can you help me to calculate the decreasing percentage of other participants? I also have a photo which describes this process. Hope it can help you. Thanks!

https://monosnap.com/file/pykMhyerN4J6s91Cs9AGtOhSAJ1Jqo

Comment: There are infinitely many ways to divide the rest of the prizes in decreasing order.

Comment: Is there a generic way to solve this problem? Maybe changing/adding some coefficient?

Comment: You could generate an exponential regression on the points you gave and use it to fill in the rest.

Comment: See my answer. Note that different prize schemes, such as the exponential regression mentioned by @dbx make way more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On average the remaining people get $\frac{1-0.4025}{96}$. You can give all the same fraction or let their prizes decrease linearly, for example. If you want strictly decreasing prizes, for a fraction $p\in(\frac{96}{239},1)$ you can give all $96$ people a fixed amount of $p\frac{1-0.4025}{96}$ and divide the rest linearly. This implies that you look for extra pieces of magnitude $x$. You give place $99$ $0x$, place $98$ $1x$, etc and place $4$ $95x$. So you need $\sum_{i=0}^{95}i=\frac12\cdot95(95+1)=4560$ extra pieces $x$. Then $x:=(1-p)\frac{1-0.4025}{4560}$. The exact prices for place $4$ to $99$ are then given by, for place $n\in\{4,5,\ldots99\}$

$$p\frac{1-0.4025}{96\cdot2}+(1-p)\frac{1-0.4025}{4560}(99-n).$$

However, different prize schemes might make much more sense since you don't have a linear prize scheme for places $1$ to $3$. The point of this post is that you have to be more specific in what you expect from the prize scheme, except from being decreasing. For every $p\in(\frac{96}{239},1)$, you find a different linear prize scheme that satisfies your conditions.

Comment: Is it easy to be replicated in Excel? Now I have something like this, you can take a look: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BpK1Kx267D7EdKiAFKXaAYPDFcStrtzKIYQnLI8ZfUk/edit#gid=1436920163

Comment: It is easily replicated in Excel but you made a mistake. The fractions do not sum up to $1$

Comment: By the way you used 10% for the second place while you mentioned 15% for the second place in you're question

Comment: Check columns G to I. You should do something like that. In that example I used $p=0.5$. Using the numbers in the Excel file, choose $p\in(\frac{96}{259},1)$